# AWK SHELL Passing Values from shell to AWK

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, awk

I need to pass a specific value from shell to a AWK script file but i dont know i cant do it.

```
    #! /bin/bash

if [ "$2" = "-C" ] && [ "$3" != "" ]; then

        awk -f SpecCity.awk $1

elif [ "$2" = "-C" ] && [ "$3" = "" ]; then

        awk -f CityOnly.awk $1

fi
```

I need to pass the value $3 to AWK which will compare it with the a file i will point but i cant do it.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use "awk -v".  For example, "awk -v city=$3..."

Newer versions of awk should also support the "ENVIRON[]" array.

Both options are discussed here:

http://unix-school.blogspot.com/2011/09/awk-passing-arguments-or-shell.html

Comment: I am using another function + it doesnt work i dont know i am getting an error each time. i try to use it. maybe i dont use it the right way.

Comment: @user1253622, paulsm4 has given you the correct answer. If it's not working, show us your awk script